# How to activate another line when clicking on another in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this parallel coordinates plot and I have some functions for mouseover and mouseout.
There are two sets of lines that go through the `first` and `second` attributes one is a solid line and the other one is a dashed-line. The dashed-line is for `"dataset":"train",` and the solid line is the one where `"dataset":"test"`.

The dashed-lines are hidden by default. When I hover over one of the solid lines they appear but when hovering over a line the other lines are set with a `opacity: .2` .

What I want to do is whenever I hover over one of the lines for dashed or solid if it belongs to `first` attribute then I want to highlight both of them. Ex. When hovering over the solid line in `first` I want the other dashed-line that belongs to `first` to have opacity 1 and not .2 . Wheares the other two lines should remain with opacity .2 when hovering over one of the lines in `first`.

I hope I was clear in explaining my problem.

Right now this is how I activate only the line I am hovering in:

```js
var dataSet = [{
    "type": "first",
    "dataset": "test",
    "Tree0": 0.1068310912868661,
    "Tree1": 0.10347688576554598,
    "Tree2": 0.11709226547153888,
    "Tree3": 0.11709226547153888,
    "Tree4": 0.11709226547153888,
    "Tree5": 0.10960380663324278,
    "Tree6": 0.10960380663324278,
    "Tree7": 0.10960380663324278,
    "Tree8": 0.10960380663324278,
  },
  {
    "type": "first",
    "dataset": "train",
    "Tree0": 1.1068310912868661,
    "Tree1": 1.10347688576554598,
    "Tree2": 1.11709226547153888,
    "Tree3": 1.11709226547153888,
    "Tree4": 1.11709226547153888,
    "Tree5": 1.10960380663324278,
    "Tree6": 1.10960380663324278,
    "Tree7": 1.10960380663324278,
    "Tree8": 1.10960380663324278,
  },
  {
    "type": "second",
    "Tree0": 0.1707001662663957,
    "Tree1": 0.007426565675226307,
    "Tree2": 0.16338444485497874,
    "Tree3": 0.16338444485497874,
    "Tree4": 0.07674117864400518,
    "Tree5": 0.09159430999445779,
    "Tree6": 0.1089229632366525,
    "Tree7": 0.1089229632366525,
    "Tree8": 0.1089229632366525
  },
  {
    "type": "second",
    "dataset": "train",
    "Tree0": 0.5068310912868661,
    "Tree1": 1.10347688576554598,
    "Tree2": 1.11709226547153888,
    "Tree3": 1.11709226547153888,
    "Tree4": 1.11709226547153888,
    "Tree5": 1.10960380663324278,
    "Tree6": 1.10960380663324278,
    "Tree7": 1.10960380663324278,
    "Tree8": 1.10960380663324278,
  }
]

var margin = {
    top: 5,
    right: 50,
    bottom: 5,
    left: 70
  },
  width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 280 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var dimensions = [{
    name: "type",
    scale: d3.scale.ordinal().rangePoints([0, height]),
    type: "string"
  },
  {
    name: "Tree0",
    scale: d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
    type: "number"
  },
  {
    name: "Tree1",
    scale: d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
    type: "number"
  },
  {
    name: "Tree2",
    scale: d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
    type: "number"
  }
];


var maxRange = d3.max(dataSet, function(d) {
  return Math.max(d.Tree0, d.Tree1, d.Tree2, d.Tree3, d.Tree4, d.Tree5, d.Tree6, d.Tree7, d.Tree8);
});

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(dimensions.map(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  }))
  .rangePoints([0, width]);

var line = d3.svg.line()
  .defined(function(d) {
    return !isNaN(d[1]);
  });

// CREATE A COLOR SCALE
var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .range(["#4683b8", "#79add2", "#a6c9de", "#cadbed", "#9d9bc4", "#bcbed9", "#dadaea", "#f6d2a8", "#f2b076", "#ef914e", "#d65e2a"])

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .orient("left");

var svg = d3.select("#parallel_coor")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var dimension = svg.selectAll(".dimension")
  .data(dimensions)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "dimension")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x(d.name) + ")";
  });

function parallel(dataSet) {
  dimensions.forEach(function(dimension) {
    dimension.scale.domain(dimension.type === "number" ?
      ([0, maxRange]) :
      dataSet.map(function(d) {
        return d[dimension.name];
      }));
  });

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "background coorPath")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(dataSet)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", draw);

  // USE THE COLOR SCALE TO SET THE STROKE BASED ON THE DATA
  foreground = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "foreground coorPath")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(dataSet)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", draw)
    .style("stroke", function(d) {
      var company = d.type.slice(0, d.type.indexOf(' '));
      return color(company);
    })

  dimension.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .each(function(d) {
      d3.select(this).call(yAxis.scale(d.scale));
    })

  // remove axis numbers
  svg.selectAll(".tick")
    .each(function(d) {
      if (typeof d == 'number') {
        this.remove();
      }
    });

  var ordinal_labels = svg.selectAll(".axis text")
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("mouseout", mouseout);

  var projection = svg.selectAll(".background path,.foreground path")
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("mouseout", mouseout);

  // d3.selectAll("[dataset=train]").attr("visibility", "hidden");
  let trainline = d3.selectAll("path").filter(function(d) {
      return d.dataset == "train";
    })
    .attr("visibility", "hidden");

  // On Click, we want to add data to the array and chart
  svg.selectAll(".coorPath path").on("mouseover", function(d) {
    // show train when click others
    trainline.attr("visibility", "visible")
    trainline.style("stroke-dasharray", ("5, 5"))
  });

  // On Click, we want to add data to the array and chart
  svg.selectAll(".coorPath path").on("mouseout", function(d) {
    // show train when click others
    trainline.attr("visibility", "hidden")
  });


  // making parallel coordinates plot interactive to highlight lines
  function mouseover(d) {
    svg.classed("active", true);

    if (typeof d === "string") {
      projection.classed("inactive", function(p) {
        return p.name !== d;
      });
      projection.filter(function(p) {
        return p.name === d;
      }).each(moveToFront);
      ordinal_labels.classed("inactive", function(p) {
        return p !== d;
      });
      ordinal_labels.filter(function(p) {
        return p === d;
      }).each(moveToFront);
    } else {
      projection.classed("inactive", function(p) {
        return p !== d;
      });
      projection.filter(function(p) {
        return p === d;
      }).each(moveToFront);
      ordinal_labels.classed("inactive", function(p) {
        return p !== d.name;
      });
      ordinal_labels.filter(function(p) {
        return p === d.name;
      }).each(moveToFront);
    }
  }

  function mouseout(d) {
    svg.classed("active", false);
    projection.classed("inactive", false);
    ordinal_labels.classed("inactive", false);
  }

  function moveToFront() {
    this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
  }


  function draw(d) {
    return line(dimensions.map(function(dimension) {
      return [x(dimension.name), dimension.scale(d[dimension.name])];
    }));
  }
}

parallel(dataSet);
```

```css
svg {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

.background path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: none;
  stroke-width: 20px;
  pointer-events: stroke;
}

.foreground path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.axis .title {
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.axis line,
.axis path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis.string {
  font-size: 6px;
}

.label {
  -webkit-transition: fill 125ms linear;
}

.active .label:not(.inactive) {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.label.inactive {
  fill: #ccc;
}

.foreground path.inactive {
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-opacity: .2;
  stroke-width: 1.2px;
}


/* body {
background-color: grey;
} */

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.node circle.highlighted {
  stroke: #00477F;
  stroke-width: 5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Create four equal columns that floats next to each other */

#svg0 {
  float: left;
  width: 120px;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
}

#svg1 {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  length: auto;
  border: 0.8px solid grey;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#svg2 {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  length: auto;
  border: 0.8px solid grey;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#svg3 {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  length: auto;
  border: 0.8px solid grey;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#svg4 {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  length: auto;
  border: 0.8px solid grey;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#svg5 {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  length: auto;
  border: 0.8px solid grey;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#svg6 {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  length: auto;
  border: 0.8px solid grey;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#svg7 {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  length: auto;
  border: 0.8px solid grey;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#svg8 {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  length: auto;
  border: 0.8px solid grey;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#svg9 {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  length: auto;
  border: 0.8px solid grey;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.treeClass {
  width: 5000px;
  height: 300px;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.treeClass:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

#scatterplots {
  width: 3000px;
}

#parallel_coor {
  /* float: right; */
  /* margin: 50px; */
  /* margin-right: 40%; */
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

#scatterplot {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 40px;
  /*margin: 20px;*/
}

#ROCPlot {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 300px;
  margin-left: 300px;
}

svg rect.borderline {
  fill: white;
  stroke-width: 0.8;
  stroke: grey;
}

.circle {
  fill: red;
}

.dot {
  fill: black;
  stroke: grey;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #aaa;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis text {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
}

ul {
  height: 28px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: -8px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}

li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

li a {
  text-size: 10px;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 7px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}

.active {
  background-color: #1679af;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="parallel_coor"></div>
```

Any help or suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it using `.filter()`, and then overriding the opacity of lines with a `type` matching the hovered line.

```js
var dataSet = [{
    "type": "first",
    "dataset": "test",
    "Tree0": 0.1068310912868661,
    "Tree1": 0.10347688576554598,
    "Tree2": 0.11709226547153888,
    "Tree3": 0.11709226547153888,
    "Tree4": 0.11709226547153888,
    "Tree5": 0.10960380663324278,
    "Tree6": 0.10960380663324278,
    "Tree7": 0.10960380663324278,
    "Tree8": 0.10960380663324278,
  },
  {
    "type": "first",
    "dataset": "train",
    "Tree0": 1.1068310912868661,
    "Tree1": 1.10347688576554598,
    "Tree2": 1.11709226547153888,
    "Tree3": 1.11709226547153888,
    "Tree4": 1.11709226547153888,
    "Tree5": 1.10960380663324278,
    "Tree6": 1.10960380663324278,
    "Tree7": 1.10960380663324278,
    "Tree8": 1.10960380663324278,
  },
  {
    "type": "second",
    "Tree0": 0.1707001662663957,
    "Tree1": 0.007426565675226307,
    "Tree2": 0.16338444485497874,
    "Tree3": 0.16338444485497874,
    "Tree4": 0.07674117864400518,
    "Tree5": 0.09159430999445779,
    "Tree6": 0.1089229632366525,
    "Tree7": 0.1089229632366525,
    "Tree8": 0.1089229632366525
  },
  {
    "type": "second",
    "dataset": "train",
    "Tree0": 0.5068310912868661,
    "Tree1": 1.10347688576554598,
    "Tree2": 1.11709226547153888,
    "Tree3": 1.11709226547153888,
    "Tree4": 1.11709226547153888,
    "Tree5": 1.10960380663324278,
    "Tree6": 1.10960380663324278,
    "Tree7": 1.10960380663324278,
    "Tree8": 1.10960380663324278,
  }
]

var margin = {
    top: 5,
    right: 50,
    bottom: 5,
    left: 70
  },
  width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 280 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var dimensions = [{
    name: "type",
    scale: d3.scale.ordinal().rangePoints([0, height]),
    type: "string"
  },
  {
    name: "Tree0",
    scale: d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
    type: "number"
  },
  {
    name: "Tree1",
    scale: d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
    type: "number"
  },
  {
    name: "Tree2",
    scale: d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
    type: "number"
  }
];


var maxRange = d3.max(dataSet, function(d) {
  return Math.max(d.Tree0, d.Tree1, d.Tree2, d.Tree3, d.Tree4, d.Tree5, d.Tree6, d.Tree7, d.Tree8);
});

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(dimensions.map(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  }))
  .rangePoints([0, width]);

var line = d3.svg.line()
  .defined(function(d) {
    return !isNaN(d[1]);
  });

// CREATE A COLOR SCALE
var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .range(["#4683b8", "#79add2", "#a6c9de", "#cadbed", "#9d9bc4", "#bcbed9", "#dadaea", "#f6d2a8", "#f2b076", "#ef914e", "#d65e2a"])

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .orient("left");

var svg = d3.select("#parallel_coor")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var dimension = svg.selectAll(".dimension")
  .data(dimensions)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "dimension")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x(d.name) + ")";
  });

function parallel(dataSet) {
  dimensions.forEach(function(dimension) {
    dimension.scale.domain(dimension.type === "number" ?
      ([0, maxRange]) :
      dataSet.map(function(d) {
        return d[dimension.name];
      }));
  });

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "background coorPath")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(dataSet)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", draw);

  // USE THE COLOR SCALE TO SET THE STROKE BASED ON THE DATA
  foreground = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "foreground coorPath")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(dataSet)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", draw)
    .style("stroke", function(d) {
      var company = d.type.slice(0, d.type.indexOf(' '));
      return color(company);
    })

  dimension.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .each(function(d) {
      d3.select(this).call(yAxis.scale(d.scale));
    })

  // remove axis numbers
  svg.selectAll(".tick")
    .each(function(d) {
      if (typeof d == 'number') {
        this.remove();
      }
    });

  var ordinal_labels = svg.selectAll(".axis text")
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("mouseout", mouseout);

  var projection = svg.selectAll(".background path,.foreground path")
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("mouseout", mouseout);

  // d3.selectAll("[dataset=train]").attr("visibility", "hidden");
  let trainline = d3.selectAll(".coorPath path").filter(function(d) {
      return d.dataset == "train";
    })
    .attr("visibility", "hidden");

  // On Click, we want to add data to the array and chart
  let lines = svg.selectAll(".coorPath path").on("mouseover", function(d) {
    // show train when click others
    trainline.attr("visibility", "visible")
    trainline.style("stroke-dasharray", ("5, 5"))
    lines.style('opacity', function(e) {
      return e.type === d.type ? 1 : 0.2;
    });
  });

  // On Click, we want to add data to the array and chart
  lines.on("mouseout", function(d) {
    // show train when click others
    lines.style('opacity', null);
    trainline.attr("visibility", "hidden")
  });


  // making parallel coordinates plot interactive to highlight lines
  function mouseover(d) {
    svg.classed("active", true);

    if (typeof d === "string") {
      projection.classed("inactive", function(p) {
        return p.name !== d;
      });
      projection.filter(function(p) {
        return p.name === d;
      }).each(moveToFront);
      ordinal_labels.classed("inactive", function(p) {
        return p !== d;
      });
      ordinal_labels.filter(function(p) {
        return p === d;
      }).each(moveToFront);
    } else {
      projection.classed("inactive", function(p) {
        return p !== d;
      });
      projection.filter(function(p) {
        return p === d;
      }).each(moveToFront);
      ordinal_labels.classed("inactive", function(p) {
        return p !== d.name;
      });
      ordinal_labels.filter(function(p) {
        return p === d.name;
      }).each(moveToFront);
    }
  }

  function mouseout(d) {
    svg.classed("active", false);
    projection.classed("inactive", false);
    ordinal_labels.classed("inactive", false);
  }

  function moveToFront() {
    this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
  }


  function draw(d) {
    return line(dimensions.map(function(dimension) {
      return [x(dimension.name), dimension.scale(d[dimension.name])];
    }));
  }
}

parallel(dataSet);
```

```css
svg {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

.background path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: none;
  stroke-width: 20px;
  pointer-events: stroke;
}

.foreground path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.axis .title {
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.axis line,
.axis path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis.string {
  font-size: 6px;
}

.label {
  -webkit-transition: fill 125ms linear;
}

.active .label:not(.inactive) {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.label.inactive {
  fill: #ccc;
}

.foreground path.inactive {
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-opacity: .2;
  stroke-width: 1.2px;
}


/* body {
background-color: grey;
} */

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.node circle.highlighted {
  stroke: #00477F;
  stroke-width: 5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Create four equal columns that floats next to each other */

#svg0 {
  float: left;
  width: 120px;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
}

#svg1 {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  length: auto;
  border: 0.8px solid grey;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#svg2 {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  length: auto;
  border: 0.8px solid grey;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#svg3 {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  length: auto;
  border: 0.8px solid grey;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#svg4 {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  length: auto;
  border: 0.8px solid grey;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#svg5 {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  length: auto;
  border: 0.8px solid grey;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#svg6 {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  length: auto;
  border: 0.8px solid grey;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#svg7 {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  length: auto;
  border: 0.8px solid grey;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#svg8 {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  length: auto;
  border: 0.8px solid grey;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#svg9 {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  length: auto;
  border: 0.8px solid grey;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.treeClass {
  width: 5000px;
  height: 300px;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.treeClass:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

#scatterplots {
  width: 3000px;
}

#parallel_coor {
  /* float: right; */
  /* margin: 50px; */
  /* margin-right: 40%; */
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

#scatterplot {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 40px;
  /*margin: 20px;*/
}

#ROCPlot {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 300px;
  margin-left: 300px;
}

svg rect.borderline {
  fill: white;
  stroke-width: 0.8;
  stroke: grey;
}

.circle {
  fill: red;
}

.dot {
  fill: black;
  stroke: grey;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #aaa;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis text {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
}

ul {
  height: 28px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: -8px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}

li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

li a {
  text-size: 10px;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 7px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}

.active {
  background-color: #1679af;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="parallel_coor"></div>
```

Comment: thank you very much! But there is one issue still. The other solid line (i.e. second) doesn't get the opacity .2. The end result I want to be only two lines with opacity 1 (one solid and the other dashed) and the other ones should get opacity .2.

Comment: Ah, I've fixed that

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Could you please try to explain just shortly how did you achieve this? or maybe add one or two comments in your code if you can please. I want to understand it.

Comment: Your code is very chaotic, all I did was add `lines.style('opacity', function(e) { return e.type === d.type ? 1 : 0.2; });` to give the lines opacity and `lines.style('opacity', null);` to revert it